# Fixed internal ips in azure

Tags: azure, hadoop, cassandra

We are currently evaluating azure, to see if we can use it for our stress and production environments.

Our environment is pretty complex, including web servers, mysql servers, hadoop and cassandra servers, as well as monitoring and deployment servers.

To set the stress environment, we need to install the environment, and then load large amounts of data into it, before we can run a stress test. This takes time and effort, and so, since we pay by the hour, we would like to be able to completely shutdown the environment, and start it up again ready to go when we want to run additional stress tests.

Here's our issue - we could not find a way to set a fixed internal ip address for a vm in azure. In AWS it is possible with VPC, but in azure, even if you define a virtual network, there seems to be no way to set a fixed internal ip (at least none that we can find).

This creates several issues for us - 
1. Hadoop relies on all nodes in the cluster being able to translate all the modes hostnames to ip addresses.
2. A cassandra cluster that has all the ip addresses in the cluster change at once freaks out. We actually lost data in a test cassandra cluster because of this.

Our questions are:
1. Is there a way to set a fixed internal ip for a vm in azure?
2. If not, did anyone have an experience with running hadoop and cassandra on azure? How did you handle the changing ip addresses when the cluster is shut down?

Any advice on these issues will be much appreciated,
Thanks
Amir

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the portal doesn't always expose all the capabilities of Azure. Some of the features in Azure are only possible through the REST API and PowerShell.
If you take a look at the new release of the PowerShell Cmdlets, you'll notice there is a new option for Static IPs in VNets.
https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools

Comment: Thanks for that. Looking at the github repo, it does mention it briefly, and I also found references to it in the repository source code. However, there's no mention of it anywhere else - specifically, no where in the cmdlet reference documentation - as far as I can tell. Can this be a feature in the works (not released yet)?